# Doctrine - ORM - Fetching all data using entityManager with associaction

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I have two entities user1 and skills, where one user will have many skills.

```
/** @Entity **/
class user1 {
    /** @Id @Column(type="integer") @GeneratedValue **/
    public $id;
    /** @Column(type="string") **/
    public $name;
    /**
     * 
     * @OneToMany(targetEntity="skills", mappedBy="uid")
     */
    public $skillset;
}

/** @Entity **/
class skills {        
    /** @Id @Column(type="integer") @GeneratedValue **/
    public $id;
    /** @Column(type="string") **/
    public $skill;
    /**
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="user1", inversedBy="skillset")
     **/
    public $uid;
}
```

But I want to fetch all the records using entityManager and getrepository like

```
$usr= $entityManager->getRepository("user1")->findAll();
```

But it gives me data from table 'user1' only. And I am not able to fetch the data from 'skills' which is associated to particular user.

'uid' is the foreign key in 'skills' table of 'id' in 'user1' table.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may prefer a `ManyToMany` relationship, because many users will have many skills.

Then you don't have to refer fields as IDs - and ORM's purpose is to hide the relational structure under the object relationship: your `$uid` field should be called `$user`.

Such said, your syntax is correct - are you sure your database schema is in sync with the entities? Have you got proper data in it? If you `var_dump` a single user, what you get?

Comment: I checked for one user, it can only fetch data related to user. I think I am not able to do mapping or association properly. And about `ManyToMany`, I strictly need `OneToMany`. Can you please give me some example for `OneToMany` ?

Comment: Though you are not using symfony, its [Doctrine guide](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html) may be useful to you.